# Exception When Trying to Create Button - Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm learning react native. I have a blank project set up using expo-cli. I have the expo app on my iPhone and am testing the app there. I am, sadly, failing to create a simple button.

First I start with a hello world app, **which is working**. Here is my App.js file simply displaying hello world:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Button} from "react-native-web";

export default function App() {
  const [outputText, setOutputText] = useState("Hello, world!");
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{outputText}</Text>
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

To add a Button that will change the text, I add the following line:

```
<Button onPress={() => setOutputText("The text changed!")} title="Change Text"/>
```

So now my App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Button} from "react-native-web";

export default function App() {
  const [outputText, setOutputText] = useState("Hello, world!");
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{outputText}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => setOutputText("The text changed!")} title="Change Text"/>
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I refresh my app and now I encounter the following error, shown on my phone:

```
Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was with the `Button` import because of `react-dom`(package required by `react-native-web`). I tried using the `Button` from `react-native` and your entire logic/code worked fine.

Remove the import

```
import {Button} from "react-native-web";
```

And import `Button` from `react-native` as such

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Any idea what the Button from the react-native-web package is for?

Comment: I think that Button from `react-native-web` can be used for web only (I'm not sure).